# Fibonacci sequence using array

Tags: fibonacci

Going to offer myself for the slaughter here.

Have checked the other questions avail, and can't seem to find the cause of my IndexOutOfRange exception for the following code:

```
public static int fib2(int n)
    {
        int[] fibarray = new int[n];

        if (n == 0) return 0;

            fibarray[0] = 0;
            fibarray[1] = 1;

            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                fibarray[i] = fibarray[i - 1] + fibarray[i - 2];

            }

            return fibarray[n];

     }
```

It's something really stupid I'm sure but it's driving me loopy (pun intended)...

Comment: tracing this in debug would tell you exactly what the problem is, try with n = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the last line!

```
return fibarray[n];
```

Your last index in your table is n-1, not n.

**Update**

And like Attila said, if n=1, the line

```
fibarray[1] = 1;
```

will also make a IndexOutOfRange

Comment: Also, `fibarray[1] = 1;` is only valid if n>=2

Comment: Yep indeed, i'll add this. Thanks !